# How to remove space from last element in array Javascript

Tags: javascript

So i am wondering how i can remove the space of last element in array.

Let's say i have a string:

```js
  let str = "d d, b b, c c, d d ";
  let split = str.split(", ");
  let arr = split.map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '_'));
  console.log(arr);
```

So as you can see i am chaining words inside array, but i have a problem that my last item in array have whitespace at the end which end with "_" at the end. How i can remove that space from the last element without removing the space between d d?

Comment: `let arr = "d d, b b, c c, d d ".trim().replace(/ /g,"_").split(",");`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).

> The `trim()` method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

```js
let str = "d d, b b, c c, d d ";
let split = str.trim().split(", ");
let arr = split.map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '_'));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.trim()` before `replace()`:

```js
let str = "d d, b b, c c, d d ";
let split = str.split(", ");
let arr = split.map(str => str.trim().replace(/\s/g, '_'));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to *match* word characters with a single space between them instead:

```js
const str = "d d, b b, c c, d d ";
const strArr = str.match(/\w+ \w+/g)
const arr = strArr.map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '_'));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is something not related with this answer, but I think you can help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443925/create-a-json-object-with-required-tree-structure

Answer (score 0):

You could trim the string before splitting.

```js
let str = "d d, b b, c c, d d ";
let split = str.trim().split(", ");
let arr = split.map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '_'));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is something not related with this answer, but I think you can help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53443925/create-a-json-object-with-required-tree-structure

Answer (score 0):

`trim` white space using `trim()` it before splitting

```js
let str = "d d, b b, c c, d d ";
let split = str.trim().split(", ");
let arr = split.map(str => str.replace(/\s/g, '_'));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim and replace before splitting

```js
console.log(
 "d d, b b, c c, d d ".trim().replace(/ /g,"_").split(",")
)
```