# Create an object with required tree structure

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to create a tree structure as:

```
var result = {
  email: {
    schema: {
      verified: 'email.verified',
      email_address: 'email.email_address',
      entity: {
        schema: {
          name: 'email.entity.name',
          type: 'email.entity.type',
          email: {
            schema: {
              verified: 'email.entity.email.verified',
              email_address: 'email.entity.email.email_address'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

From the array data as given below:

```
var schema = {
  'paths': [
    'email.email_address',
    'email.entity.email.email_address',
    'email.entity.email.verified',
    'email.entity.type',
    'email.entity.name',
    'email.verified',
    'created_at',
    'contact_numbers'
  ]
}
```

You see that the output I expect has `schema` property nested withing `n` levels and that is not predictable. It depends on the value of the `paths` like as in `'email.entity.email.email_address'`. You can split that with dot and seemingly each dot is replaced with `schema` property in the output.

I am trying to use recursion, but I am not able to set that flow. Below is the code I have tried so far:

```js
var schema = {
  'paths': [
    'email.email_address',
    'email.entity.email.email_address',
    'email.entity.email.verified',
    'email.entity.type',
    'email.entity.name',
    'email.verified',
    'created_at',
    'contact_numbers'
  ]
}
var newSchema = {};

var key = 'email';
var existKeys = schema.paths.filter((path) => path.includes(key + '.'));
var requiredObject = {};
existKeys.forEach((existKey) => {
  var splitKeys = existKey.split('.');
  splitKeys.forEach((splitKey, index) => {
    if (requiredObject[splitKey] && index + 1 === splitKeys.length) {
      requiredObject[splitKey].schema = existKey;
    } else {
      requiredObject[splitKey] = {
        'schema': {}
      }
    }
  });
});
console.log(requiredObject);
```

Comment: Is that the actual relationship of the array data to the expected output? It would seem easier to hardcode the keys and access the array via indices for the values

Comment: Shouldn't there be `created_at` and `contact_numbers` properties on the top level too?

Comment: Not exactly pretty but it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/bm475Ljp/

Comment: @CertainPerformance I need to filter that for `email` only. The code I have posted has `key` with `email` and I need the schema for that `email` on top level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the paths and take for every found key a `schema` property as well.

```js
var schema = { paths: ['email.email_address', 'email.entity.email.email_address', 'email.entity.email.verified', 'email.entity.type', 'email.entity.name', 'email.verified', 'created_at', 'contact_numbers'] },
    result = schema.paths
        .filter(s => s.startsWith('email')) // or not or so, if so, maybe
        .reduce((r, p) => {
            var keys = p.split('.'),
                last = keys.pop();

            keys.reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = o[k] || { schema: {} }).schema, r)[last] = p;
            return r;
        }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I am really thankful to you Nina. I was certain that you would surely help me. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd `reduce` over the `paths` array, using a helper function `assignNested` which, given an outer object, a value, and a property array, uses the top property to create the `schema` object and recursively call itself, until the array has only one item left, and the final value can be assigned:

```js
var schema = {
  'paths': [
    'email.email_address',
    'email.entity.email.email_address',
    'email.entity.email.verified',
    'email.entity.type',
    'email.entity.name',
    'email.verified',
    'created_at',
    'contact_numbers'
  ]
};

function assignNested(obj, val, props) {
  if (props.length === 1) {
    obj[props[0]] = val;
    return;
  }
  const nextProp = props.shift();
  if (!obj.schema) obj.schema = {};
  if (!obj.schema[nextProp]) obj.schema[nextProp] = {};
  assignNested(obj.schema[nextProp], val, props);
}

const fullResult = schema.paths.reduce((a, path) => {
  const props = path.split('.');
  assignNested(a, path, props);
  return a;
}, {});

// fullResult contains the *full* structure,
// but if you only want the nested `email` part, then:
const result = {
  email: {
    schema: fullResult.schema.email
  }
};
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 2 `Array.reduce` you can achieve like below

```js
var schema = {
  'paths': [
    'email.email_address',
    'email.entity.email.email_address',
    'email.entity.email.verified',
    'email.entity.type',
    'email.entity.name',
    'email.verified',
    'created_at',
    'contact_numbers'
  ]
}

let res = schema.paths.reduce((o, d) => {
  let keys = d.split('.')
  keys.reduce((t, k, i) => {
    t[k] = (i != keys.length - 1)
              ? (t[k] || { schema: {} })
              : d

    return t[k].schema
  }, o)
  
  return o
}, {})

console.log(res)

// for only email
console.log({ email: res.email })
```